# CPU percent of running process

Tags: python, subprocess, cpu-usage, psutil

I'm trying to get the percent of `CPU` usage for an external process in `python`. I've seen some other posts on this topic, but haven't helped me too much. When I run the following function I get values that aren't consistent with what I'm seeing in `task manager`. For example, if I'm monitoring a chrome process I get values that oscillate between 1 and 2, but task manager shows values oscillating between 25 and 30. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
def monitor(pid):
    cpu_table = []
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    while p.is_running():
        cpu_table.append(p.get_cpu_percent())
        time.sleep(1)
    return cpu_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are several chrome processes and you might be monitoring the wrong one
2. [`cpu_percent()` *"compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import"*](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.cpu_percent). Pass the same `interval` that task manager uses (in case, it is not 1 second). Make sure to start both your `monitor()` function and the task manager at the same time.